# If no products are on sale - hide ID or class

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

Sorry for the simplicity of this question, but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere. Is there an existing sales hook in woocommerce?

Like:

```
<?php
   if ( on_sale == 0 ) {
     echo '<style>.specials {display:none;};
     }
?>
```

That is essentially all I am trying to accomplish. I have a row/column that displays products on sale... I just want to hide that if there are currently no products on sale.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you displaying those products? Knowing that will help us answer the question.

Comment: I have them displayed on y homepage in a slider row (bootstrap and owl carousel).

Essentially just want to hide this row if no products are on sale but can't find a hook or filter for it,

Comment: Post the code you are using. Are you using your own Query? How are you outputting your code? Without seeing your code we are just guessing.